# How to save image object variable as picture in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I have generated an image using

```
im = imagesc(tt,ff,log10(abs(wv))); axis off;
```

But there are two problems:

1. This pops up a figure window each time after executing the above command. How can I avoid that?
2. How can I save this figure as a picture without border?

Comment: `imagesc` is for creating a figure window. If you don't want a figure window, don't use that command. Instead, use [`imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) to save the matrix as an image file. You likely want to scale it first, for example `img = log10(abs(wv)); img = img / max(img(:)); imwrite(img,'filename.png');`.

Comment: these commands doesn't give satisfying result. `I ran img= log10(abs(wv))`; Then `im = img / max(img(:));` Then `imshow(img)` this gives a very small image in black & white color. I used `img = ind2rgb(uint8(img), jet(8))` But this also doesn't give any result like `imagesc(tt,ff,log10(abs(wv)));`

Answer (score 1):

As Cris has mentioned in the comments, imagesec is for displaying data in array as an image. If you want to save to just save such image you should use imwrite which is used to save image variables as an image file. In case your variable has not the proper format ind2rgb to convert the indexed image to RGB format.

you can find the duplicate question [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/383957-how-can-i-save-the-output-of-imagesc-as-the-exact-resolution) in mathworks forums.